# rails has_many through and Multiple databases causing SQLite::BusyException

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I have a rails application that is using multiple sqlite3 databases (That part is non negotiable), and I have the following classes

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "users_#{Rails.env}" # use alternate DB
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :groups, through => :memberships
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   establish_connection "users_#{Rails.env}" # use alternate DB
   has_many :memberships
   has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :group
   belongs_to :user
   # validations stuff
   establish_connection "users_#{Rails.env}" # use alternate DB
end
```

When I create user with a group I get a the following:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "memberships" ...
```

However when I remove the "establish_connection" method call, and use the single default database, everything works fine and as expected.

I have tried increasing the timeout in database.yml to be 15 seconds, but the same exception just takes longer to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen too. A few things to try:

- Up the timeout in database.yml to 10-15 seconds. You already did this, but it may help someone else with this problem. If you have a slow hard drive and a lot of test data, maybe 20+
- Either delete and re-create the database (if this is in development that probably shouldn't be a problem), or restore a backup of it. There might be a problem with it as it is currently. Incorrectly shutting down the development server, maybe?
- May be a stretch, but make sure the permissions on the file are correct.

Comment: Permissions are the same on the default database, as the users database, so that isnt the problem, since the default db works fine. Have tried deleting and recreating the db from scratch. No luck there. A 20 second timeout on the db just makes the app pause for 20seconds before throwing the same exception. I've even tried a 1 minute timeout, but the same error occurs. Maybe its time to go digging into the rails establish_connection source